# How can I improve the time it takes on a per-row function operation on a dataframe causing: Error: Socket exception: Operation timed out (60)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this notebook python script that needs to traverse 1.7-million-record dataframe
the script has unique service records and creates a pivot table based on client id (rows), and counts service id's per status (columns: active, suspended, deactivated and cancelled), then, it turns that pivot table into a dataframe (clients_df), this operation appears to complete fine and really quick.

the problem is when I try to added 2 columns to that clients_df, one that gets the date of the first service that was acquired for each client id and another column that finds the date the last service was cancelled if the client id has 0 active services. both of this columns are added through a np.vecorize operation (in hope that the iteration can be done as fast as possible).

these are the 2 functions that iterate through each client id in the clients_df dataframe resulting from the pivot operation on the original dataframe (uber_df: which has service records) to get the date the first service was acquired and the date the last service was cancelled, respectively

```
#Date the client acquired their first service
def getFirstServiceBillingStartDateSegment0(clientID):
  #from uber_df (services df), get set of services that belong to client, only the billing start date column
  temp_df = uber_df.loc[(uber_df['ClientID']==clientID) & (uber_df['BillingStartDate(Revised)']!='err')].sort_values(['BillingStartDate(Revised)'], ascending=(True))
  if len(temp_df) > 0:
    return temp_df.iloc[0]['BillingStartDate(Revised)'] #first row's billing start date
  else:
    return 'err' #because every service that belongs to a client should have a billing start date if not an err should be reported
#clients_df['Date Client was Acquired'] = clients_df['ClientID'].map(getFirstServiceBillingStartDate)
#clients_df['Date Client was Acquired'] = np.vectorize(getFirstServiceBillingStartDate)(clients_df['ClientID'])

#Date Client Churned segment0
#---------------------
#Date the client cancelled their last service
def getLastServiceCanceledDateSegment0(clientID):
  #from uber_df (services df), get set of services that belong to client and that are either canceled or deactivated
  temp_df = uber_df.loc[(uber_df['ClientID']==clientID) & (uber_df['ServiceStatus'].isin(['Canceled','Deactivated'])) & (uber_df['EndDate(Revised)']!='err')].sort_values(['EndDate(Revised)'], ascending=(False))
  if len(temp_df) > 0:
    return temp_df.iloc[0]['EndDate(Revised)'] #first row's EndDate start and get the date last cancelation date from the set of services
  else:
    return 'err' #because every cancelled/deactivated service that belongs to the client should have a cancel date, if not an err should be reported
#clients_df['Date Client Churned'] = clients_df.loc[clients_df['A/S Services']==0]['ClientID'].map(getLastServiceCanceledDate)
#clients_df['Date Client Churned'] = np.vectorize(getLastServiceCanceledDate)(clients_df['A/S Services']==0]['ClientID'])
```

the problem I'm facing is that adding this 2 columns appears to be taking quite too long. As i write this I'm just getting close to the 24h mark of having the cell running and the script described above hasn't finished yet. this morning I woke up to an error that reads: `ERROR | Socket exception: Operation timed out (60)`, yet the notebook is still executing with glass clock up in the browser tab icon and the [*] in the cell where the code is running.

my questions:

1. is there a way to know if I'm just wasting my time waiting for the code to finish running, given that I got that operation time out error?
2. can I set something in anaconda or jupyter so there's no timeout regardless how long it takes?
3. should I do this differently, if so, how?

at the moment, I re-started the same operation, on another machine,but on a subset of my original dataframe (a segment of it based on a categorical column (region)), in hope to be able to move on and be able to et resulting dataframe (clients_df) as I still need to use that daframe as input for another operation similar to the one above with functions similar to the functions provided.

Comment: Did you try [Modin](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) yet? Since it is a single line change, it may be worth a try. See https://twitter.com/jayzpio/status/1633851051559223298 , that discussion itself may give you some other ideas.